# Integral representation of Hurwitz Zeta function that works for all arguments?

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Is there a known integral representation of Hurwitz Zeta function which works at all arguments where Hurwitz Zeta is defined?

The representations in Wikipedia have limited range.

Comment: With integral you mean no series? The easiest formula is a series plus an integral.

Comment: @reuns well, integral is better, but if the formula uses series but works for all arguments, then it is better than nothing.

Comment: In fact it works only for $\Re(a)>0$: $$\sum_{n\ge 0} (n+a)^{-s}= \frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{(1-a)x}}{e^x-1}dx$$ $$=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_1^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}e^{(1-a)x}}{e^x-1}dx+\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{B_k(1-a)}{k!} \frac1{(s+k-1)\Gamma(s)}$$ Same for the contour integral.

Comment: @reuns that's sad. I need a representation, continuous at zero.

Comment: Sure, continuous at $0$...

Comment: @reuns by $s$...

Comment: It is valid (and analytic) for $\Re(a)>0,s\in \Bbb{C}-1$, and the advantage is that the proof is trivial.

Comment: @reuns my aim is to have a representation for this function in terms of integrals: $$\frac{-((n-1) \zeta (n,0))+(n-1) \zeta (n,1)+\int_0^{\infty } (n-1) n t^{-n-1} \, dt}{\Gamma (2-n)}=\frac{-B_{1-n}+B_{1-n}(1)+\int_0^{\infty } (n-1) n t^{-n-1} \, dt}{\Gamma (2-n)}$$

Comment: @reuns if I insert $s=0$ in your formula, it gives 0. If I insert in my formula $n=0$, the overall result is 1.

Comment: No it doesn't give $0$.

Comment: @reuns $1/\Gamma(0)=0$, is not it? I have already tried these representations in Mathematica.

Comment: @reuns $$\frac{\int_0^{\infty } (n-1) n t^{-n-1} \, dt-\frac{(n-1) \int_0^{\infty } t^{n-1} \, dt}{\Gamma (n)}}{\Gamma (2-n)}$$ at $n=0$ gives 0, but should give 1.

Comment: @Anixx Are you aware of the fact that $\zeta(n,0)=\zeta(n,1)$?

Comment: @vitamind no, they are not always equal. $\zeta (0,1)=-1/2, \zeta (0,0)=1/2$

Comment: I understood $n$ as ${n}\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. If $n\notin\mathbb{N}$ this relation is of course not always true.

Comment: @vitamind that I use the variable $n$ is a coincidence, I just copied the formulas from Mathematica where I initially wrote them down using Bernoulli polynomials... I am interested in real(or complex) $n$.